# save image on file system instead of DB

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I m developping an application where user can provide text informations and images. I want to save images on file system and in DB, I will add a link of each user to its images So I need to add the user ID to the image name to not get images with same name. I m using SPRING MVC.
in my Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add ( @RequestParam("prix") Long prix, 
            RequestParam("adresse") String ville,
            @RequestParam("categorie") String categorie,
            @RequestParam("photos") MultipartFile file,
            ) throws FileNotFoundException


 {

   String chemin=null;
   if (!file.isEmpty())
     {
      try {
       String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
       // this line to retreive just file name 
       String 
       name=orgName.substring(orgName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,orgName.length());
       chemin="e:\\images\\"+name;  //here I want to add id (auto generated)
       File file1=new File(chemin);
       file.transferTo(file1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }

    }
    annonce.setImage(chemin);
    annonce.setTitre(prix);
    annonce.setCorps(ville);
    annonce.setPrix(cetegorie)
    annoncedao.save(annonce);
    return "SuccessAddAnnonce";
}
```

but I can not get the ID witch is auto generated so I can not get it throw @RequestParam like adress or categorie because it is auto generated and I still don t have it until we call save method witch is last .
Any suggestions are welcome .

Comment: you want to generate a random ID for a user?

Comment: no, each time I add a user an ID is generated , I want to get the last ID from the Database

Comment: you didnt tell which DB it is, mysql? and on what is its schema, so i can help

Comment: sorry , yes it s MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Id using query with Select max (id)
@Query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Annonce")
    Long findAutoincrementAnnonce();

I wish help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random ID for each user and assign it to a particular user, and thus its image name also (what you intend to do here I guess).

I will illustrate it simply.

```
// Get a random ID coressponding to the user address or whatever, here i will just use address

MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(ville.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String randomId = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);

// Here you have a uniqueID for an address.
// You could have just used ville.hashCode() also but it might give you collisions with some different Strings.
```

if Input: "64th Street, Downtown, StackOverFlow" then

randomId = 8AB126F8EBC0F7B5CCBBEB3E21582ADF